# How to combine information from $_ ($PSItem ) into the new output items

Tags: powershell

Using AWS Powershell, we can get regions with `Get-EC2Region`

```
PS> Get-EC2Region
PS /home/cloudshell-user> Get-EC2Region               

Endpoint                         OptInStatus         RegionName
--------                         -----------         ----------
ec2.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com     opt-in-not-required ap-south-1
ec2.eu-north-1.amazonaws.com     opt-in-not-required eu-north-1
...
ec2.us-west-1.amazonaws.com      opt-in-not-required us-west-1
ec2.us-west-2.amazonaws.com      opt-in-not-required us-west-2
```

We can get Vpc of each region with

```
PS> Get-EC2Vpc -Region ap-southeast-1

CidrBlock                   : 10.0.0.0/16
CidrBlockAssociationSet     : {vpc-cidr-assoc-...}
DhcpOptionsId               : dopt-...
InstanceTenancy             : default
Ipv6CidrBlockAssociationSet : {}
IsDefault                   : False
OwnerId                     : ...
State                       : available
Tags                        : {Name}
VpcId                       : vpc-...
```

To get all Vpc, I can pipe it like this

```
PS> Get-EC2Region | %{ Get-EC2Vpc -Region $_.RegionName }
```

However, what if I want the "RegionName" as part of the output ? I've tried with

```
PS> Get-EC2Region `
    | %{ Get-EC2Vpc -Region $_.RegionName `
         | Select-Object *, `
             @{ name="RegionName"; expression={$_.RegionName} } }
CidrBlock                   : 10.0.0.0/16
CidrBlockAssociationSet     : {vpc-cidr-assoc-...}
DhcpOptionsId               : dopt-...
InstanceTenancy             : default
Ipv6CidrBlockAssociationSet : {}
IsDefault                   : False
OwnerId                     : ...
State                       : available
Tags                        : {Name}
VpcId                       : vpc-...
RegionName                  :
```

But it does not work. The newly defined "RegionName" is empty. How to define expression using $_ or $PSItem in general ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work

```
Get-EC2Region -PipelineVariable Regions | 
    ForEach-Object { 
        Get-EC2Vpc -Region $_.RegionName | 
            Select-Object *, @{ name = 'RegionName'; expression = { $Regions.RegionName } }
        }
```

Comment: Learn new thing here. Thanks !

Comment: `-PipelineVariable` is underused(even by myself). Just note I'm not sure it's the most efficient way to do this

Answer (score 0):

StackOverflow do not allow AI generated answer. But I indeed find out this by asking AI :)

```
PS> Get-EC2Region `
     | %{ $r = $_.RegionName;Get-EC2Vpc -Region $r `           
          | Select-Object *, `
              @{ name="RegionName"; expression={$r} } }
```